# Is Manipura, mentioned in Mahabharata, the same place as the current Indian state of Manipura?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, india, geography

Arjuna married Chitragnda - the princess of the Manipura. Is this the same place as the current Indian state of Manipura?

Comment: The current Indian state of Manipur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it is not!

Mahabharata Adi Parva, Arjuna Vanavasa Parva [Chapter 217](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc4290.html) describes Arjuna's pilgrimage route.

Getting down from the Himalayas, he went eastward. He visited many famous pilgrimage sites in Anga (Bihar-Jharkhand) and Vanga (Bengal). For example, he went to Gaya kshetra. Then he went to Kalinga (Odisha).

From Kalinga, he went to Mahendra Parvat (Parasurama's ashrama was situated there in ancient times. It is part of the Sahyadri or Eastern Ghat mountain range).

From there, he went along the seashore and reached Manipur. So Manipur of Mahabharata was situated in Andhra or maybe in the modern-day Andhra-Odisha border. But definitely, it has no connection with the current Manipura state.

Here I am quoting the relevant verses from "A prose English translation of the Mahabharata (translated literally from the original Sanskrit text)" by Manmatha Nath Dutt, 1895, Calcutta. I have also added the link to the Mahabharata by Kisari Mohan Ganguly. Though unfortunately, in that book, verse numbers are not there.

> Whatever Tirthas and other holy places were in Anga, Banga and Kalinga, he went to all of them. **- Mahabharata 1.217.9**

> Crossing (the country of) the Kalingas and seeing on his way many countries, holy places, and charming mansions, that lord proceeded on. **- Mahabharata 1.217.12**

> Seeing the Mahendra mountain adorned with the ascetics and going slowly along the seashores, he went to Manipur. **- Mahabharata 1.217.13**

> To the king of Manipur, the virtuous Chitravahana, who had a beautiful daughter named Chitrangada. **- Mahabharata 1.217.15**

Comment: Very well. had liked yesterday’s Q and had put a comment to find Manipura location but then deleted it. You can add a Tamil folklore of Alli and Arjuna maybe related to Chitrangada and Arjuna. Some say Alli is from Tamil Nadu only (south). But we don’t know which kingdom - Pandya chola Kerala?

Comment: @Archit, I do not know about that Tamil folklore. If you know, please add it as an answer.

Comment: I don’t have a source sorry. Well see later

Comment: It just says from Kalinga, he went along sea-shore. It doesn't say south or north. He could have gone north along sea-shore, and Manipur is right there. It is very strange that you accept Anga as current state Bihar, Vanga as the current Stage Bengal, Kalinga as current state Odisha, but not Manipura as current state Manipur @Archit

Comment: @mar point sounds possible.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay you are right bannaje told that Arjuna married pandya princess

Answer (score 0):

Its mentioned east of Himalaya, It mentioned Ganga which ended in Bangladesh that is too close to north-east India. Manipur is in east of Himalaya. In Mahabharata it is mentioned the king of Manipura as king of Nagas, Nagas are Chandravanshi the people who lives in extreme east and North-East India. People of odissa were never considered as naga community. This the reason we have two Sakti pith in North-East India, Maa Tripureswari of Tripura and Maa Kamakhya in Assam. This is why Maa Durga is worshipped in Bengal and whole North-East. The crescent moon on Shivas head also symbolises Chandravanshi's, the loved people of Shiva.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).